# Ruby on rails: mysql error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

**I'm using windows xp 32 pro, bit, sp3. the latest version of [railsinstaller](http://railsinstaller.org), and `mysql2 gem`**

i have been trying to solve this error all this week. When i run `rake db:create` I see this error

[image]

[this is what i see when i trace the error](http://i1201.photobucket.com/albums/bb354/elieobeid7/rorerror2.jpg)

i have solved this error by downloading [the zipped version of mysql Connector/C 6.0.2 for 32 bit](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/) and copying `libmysql.dll` from `mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32-vs2005\lib`

to `C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.2\bin`

now when I run `rake db:create` i see

[image]

[and this is what i see when i trace the error](http://i1201.photobucket.com/albums/bb354/elieobeid7/rorerror4.jpg)

i hope these info will help you, to help me solve the problem :)

**@phoet**

**my gemfile**

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2'
gem 'cucumber'
gem 'database_cleaner'
gem 'cucumber-rails'
gem 'capybara'
gem 'rspec', '2.8'
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.8'
gem 'launchy'
gem 'spork'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
end
```

**my db config**

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: selvista
  username: root
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql
  database: selvista_test
  username: root
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: mysql
  database: selvista_prod
  username: root
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

should my adapter be `mysql2`?

Comment: give any solution you think will work, I NEVER vote down answers, because who answers my questions is trying to help

Comment: please post the db config and the gemfile you are using. i assume that you did not properly define the mysql dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to put mysql2 on your adapter lines in you database.yml.

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: selvista
  username: root
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: selvista_test
  username: root
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: selvista_prod
  username: root
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```